# Dental System Logic - Users - Database

Tags: database, security, database-design, relational-database, business-logic

I'm developping a new dental system that will be used for Dentist in some specific countries. I have the basic requirements and design almost done but I'm not really sure how to handle pacients. These are my 2 options:

1. Add all pacientes in a single table (pacient_table) and create a link between pacient-dentist in another table (link_table), where I would store pacient_id and dentist_id. Doing this, if any other dentist adds the same pacient , they will just need to add the ID of that person and all the details would be automatically retrieve and a new link created with that dentist.
2. Create a new database for each dentist. Doing this multiple instances of the same pacient could exist (this should not be a problem).

I think I prefer option 1) because I like the idea to have 1 pacient and multiple links between that pacient and the dentist and not the same pacient added by each dentist.

Please let me know which option you think is the best one and why.
New options are also welcome :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're certainly on the right track with #1.
Perhaps the best design in this case is to use a single database comprised of three tables.

The first table, dentist, will store all attributes (columns) regarding each dentist at the office, with dentist_id as it's primary key.  This table represents the entity 'dentist'.  Each row will of course represent an individual dentist.

The second table, patient, will store all relevant attributes (columns) regarding each patient, with patient_id as it's primary key.  This table represents the entity 'patient'.  Similar to above, each row represents an individual patient.

The third table is (conceptually) placed in between dentist and patient, perhaps name it 'treatment', 'visitation', or some similar appropriate name (the link table you mentioned).  The purpose of this table is to capture and represent the event of a patient visiting with a dentist.  It would have it's own primary key, with dentist_id and patient_id as foreign keys.  It could also include date_of_visit, etc.  This third table is a composite entity, and it unifies and gives structure to the dentist and patient relationship.

A proper query of such a schema would reveal which dentist consulted with which patients, when it took place; as well as which dentists have treated the most patients, and so on.

I hope this helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Option one is architecturally "pure".  It however suffers from the reality that businesses don't like to share data with others.  In my experience, businesses are not likely to appreciate the fact that the record they spent quite a bit of effort developing might be used directly by a competitor.

For that reason, I suggest that Option 2 is more sound from a business standpoint.

Also note that in many western countries there are severe limits on how medical data can be handled.  In the USA, you would not be able to sell this without a lot of certification and indemnity insurance and the backing of a large corporation.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for taking time to answer it :) Regarding option 1, end-user (dentist) will not know that all the pacients are being stored in the same table. All queries to will be performed on the relation_table (using the dentist_id) and based on that I will retrieve the pacient details. I agree on the last statement, I know that I will not be able to operate in some specific countries without some certifications.

Thank you much!

Comment: Savvy business owners will ask such questions.